# how to implement push notification in ionic for ios using Fcm

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

i have setup all the steps for push notification using https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/first-message#access_the_registration_token but i didn't get notification in ios App but working in Android App . please help me resolving this